# Passing Attributes as Arguments

Tags: python-2.7

I have a number of attributes on a class that contain integers as values. Based on a user's current selection, all the data for a given attribute may equal zero, in which case I don't want to display it.

I'm trying to define a function to check each attribute:

```
def NoneCheck(collegelist, attribute):
    e = []
    for college in collegelist:
        e.append(int(college.attribute))
    if sum(e) == 0:
        attribute = False
    else:
        attribute = True
    return attribute
```

But I end up with the error:

```
'Inventories' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

Obviously 'attribute' is not being passed to college.attribute, but is instead being read literally as an 'attribute' attribute. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want `getattr` [[docs]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), which gets an attribute from its name.  For example:

```
def NoneCheck(collegelist, attribute):
    return sum(getattr(coll, attribute) for coll in collegelist) != 0
```

gives

```
>>> NoneCheck([Inventory(0), Inventory(0)], 'book')
False
>>> NoneCheck([Inventory(0), Inventory(4)], 'book')
True
>>> NoneCheck([Inventory(0), Inventory(4)], 'undefined')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-4aae80aba985>", line 1, in <module>
    NoneCheck([Inventory(0), Inventory(4)], 'undefined')
  File "<ipython-input-1-424558a8260f>", line 2, in NoneCheck
    return sum(getattr(coll, attribute) for coll in collegelist) == 0
  File "<ipython-input-1-424558a8260f>", line 2, in <genexpr>
    return sum(getattr(coll, attribute) for coll in collegelist) == 0
AttributeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute 'undefined'
```

I should say, though, that I seldom use `getattr` and `setattr` myself.  Whenever you need to apply something to many attributes at once, you realize you need to put their names somewhere so you can loop over them.. and if you're doing that, you might as well use a `dict` to start with!

Comment: The issue here, as I understand it, is that getattr must receive the attribute name as a string (e.g. getattr(obj, 'attr'), so it cannot take a variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I could pass the name as a string and it would work. Thanks for the solution!